# How do i combine Ip face adaptors and control-net stable diffusion

Tags: stable-diffusion

I am trying to make a flow of stable diffusion that combines the potent ability with stable the Ip face adaptor, i am able to use adaptor to generate faces but i wanna transfer the pos from one pic to another